# httpd.conf Alias does not work for www version of site

Tags: apache, alias, httpd.conf, no-www

I recently added a favicon to a Django site by editing my httpd.conf file:

Alias /favicon.ico /home/learntango/webapps/staticapp/site_images/favicon.ico

This works for no-www, but not for www.:

- Works:    http://learntodancetango.com/
- Doesn't:  http://www.learntodancetango.com/

Any advice?

**Thanks!**

David

---

Full httpd.conf file for reference:

> ```
> ServerRoot "/home/learntango/webapps/django/apache2"
>
> LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
> LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
> LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
> LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
> LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
> LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
> LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
> LoadModule alias_module      modules/mod_alias.so
>
> Alias /favicon.ico /home/learntango/webapps/staticapp/site_images/favicon.ico
>
> LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
> CustomLog /home/learntango/logs/user/access_django.log combined
> ErrorLog /home/learntango/logs/user/error_django.log
> KeepAlive Off
> Listen 32691
> MaxSpareThreads 3
> MinSpareThreads 1
> ServerLimit 1
> SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
> ThreadsPerChild 5
> WSGIDaemonProcess django processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/home/learntango/webapps/django:/home/learn
> tango/webapps/django/lib/python2.7
> WSGIProcessGroup django
> WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
> WSGILazyInitialization On
> WSGIScriptAlias / /home/learntango/webapps/django/mysite.wsgi
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on my side. Did you clear your browser caches ?

Comment: I was experimenting with no-www ... that's why it worked.  I stopped experimenting, and you can see that it doesn't work... (also, I just cleared cache)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, although I don't know why it didn't work earlier!

Comment: Probably your browser's local cache!